# Do algorithms reduce?

Tags: complexity-theory

Given two problems A and B.

Given two algorithms a' and b'. a' solves A and b' solves B.

If A reduces to B and B reduces to A.

Then can we say anything about a' and b'? Are they the same?

Answer (score 2):

A reduction can be thought of a way to "rephrase" a problem in terms
of another. This can be denoted using $A \to B$, $A$ reduces to
$B$. This means that **if** you have an algorithm that solves $B$
**then** you also have an algorithm that solves $A$, since $A$ reduces
to $B$, $A \to B$. Now you also have $B \to A$ so in some way, your
problems are equivalent since they can be reduced to each other.

However, this does not imply much about the algorithms themselves
because they can be arbitrarily bad. For example, the sorting problem
has time complexity $O(n \log n)$. But an awful algorithm that sorts by
testing all possible permutations has time complexity $O(n!)$.

The only thing we can say is that the algorithms aren't better (their
time complexity isn't lower than) the problems themselves.

Answer (score 0):

What do you *want* to say about $a'$ and $b'$?  They can't possibly be the same algorithm unless $A=B$, since one of them solves $A$ and the other one doesn't.  Even if $A=B$, they're not necessarily the same algorithm: if there's one algorithm that solves some problem, there are infinitely many (your favourite algorithm; count to two and then do your favourite algorithm; count to three and...).

It's so obvious that $a'$ and $b'$ are different except in trivial cases that having to ask the question suggests that you've misunderstood something, but I'm not sure what, so I can't be more helpful at the moment.